# Inference for Contingency tables

Tags: inference, contingency-tables

Assume two paired binary vectors, $v^A,v^B$. We can easily construct a contingency table looking like:

|  | $v^A_i=1$ | $v^A_i=0$ | Totals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $v^B_i=1$ | $a$ | $b$ | $a+b$ |
| $v^B_i=0$ | $c$ | $d$ | $c+d$ |
| **Totals** | $a+c$ | $b+d$ | $a+b+c+d=p$ |

Usually we infer using the $\chi^2$ statistic $$\frac{(\text{observed-expected})^2}{\text{expected}}$$
Or using [McNemar's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) where: $$\frac{(b-c)^2}{b+c}\sim\chi^2.$$ However, the book [Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis (Johnson & Wichern, 2013)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131877151) (p. 675) offers some other summative statistics derived from the contingency table:

> **Table 12.1** Similarity Coefficients for Clustering Items*

|  | Coefficient | Rationale |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | $\frac{a+d}{p}$ | Equal weights for 1-1 matches and 0-0 matches. |  |
| 2. | $\frac{2(a+d)}{2(a+d)+b+c}$ | Double weight for 1-1 matches and 0-0 matches. |  |
| 3. | $\frac{a+d}{ a+d+2(b+c) }$ | Double weight for unmatched pairs. |  |
| 4. | $\frac{a}{p}$ | No 0-0 matches in numerator. |  |
| 5. | $\frac{a}{a+b+c}$ | No 0-0 matches in numerator or denominator. (The 0-0 matches are treated as irrelevant.) |  |
| 6. | $\frac{2a}{2a+b+c}$ | No 0-0 matches in numerator or denominator. Double weight for 1-1 matches. |  |
| 7. | $\frac{a}{a+2(b+c)}$ | No 0-0 matches in numerator or denominator. Double weight for unmatched pairs. |  |
| 8. | $\frac{a}{b+c}$ | Ratio of matches to mismatches with 0-0 matches excluded |  |

> *[$p$ binary variables; see (12-7).]

My null hypothesis is $H_0:v^A,v^B \text{ are independent}$. Assuming that I want to use one of these measures (each fits a somewhat different alternative), what can I assume regarding their distribution? It's clear this ain't $\chi^2$, but what is it?

Another possible difficulty might rise from the fact that we don't have the "real" binary vectors $v^A,v^B$ but rather their estimates $\hat{v}^A,\hat{v}^B$. What effect does it have, if any?

---

Just for comparison with the table 12.1 reproduced above, here is an image of the table as it appears originally in the book:

[image: Similarity coefficients]

Comment: This is unanswerable. You know *a priori* that the distribution of the variable pair is determined by three parameters, such as the marginal success rates and the correlation. The distribution of any statistic, like the 8 given in the table, is determined by the sample size and those three parameters. If you adopt some specific null hypothesis, it can narrow the possibilities substantially. **What is your null hypothesis??** Furthermore, the chi-squared statistic (obviously) does *not* have a chi-squared distribution: that's an approximation.  **What approximations are you willing to use?**

Comment: note these are not success rates but rather success counts (i.e. $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$). Regarding hypotheses - each of the 8 coefficients fits a different hypothesis and different assumptions regarding the willingness to penalize for disagreements. Regarding approximations - I'm open for suggestions.

Comment: By "hypothesis" I mean a true null hypothesis in the standard statistical sense of the term.  This restricts the set of possible distributions.  Without such a restriction, *nothing can be said* about the distribution of any statistic.

Comment: In that case, I'd go with something like "$v^A,v^B$ are independent"

Comment: Please include that important qualification in your post!